# Designing a web based game that would run in a browser - Where should I start?

Tags: python, web-applications

I would like to design a web based game preferably in Python ( using Django maybe) though I'm open to any language other than Java/Flash/ActionScript. The idea I have in mind is more about data models than graphics and will leverage social networking sites. I would like to extend it with a mobile web interface in the future. Please give your invaluable suggestions and recommend some resources with which I can get started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1.  Design a good game.

Step 2.  Be sure that it fits the HTTP model of simple request/reply GET/POST processing.  Be sure that the game is still good.  Some people try to do "real time" or "push" or other things that don't fit the model well and require lots of sophisticated GUI on the desktop.

Step 3.  Find a web framework.  Django is okay.  Others are good too.
Learn the web framework.  Don't start with your game.  Start with the tutorials.

Step 4.  Rethink your game.  Be sure that it fits the framework's model, as well as the HTTP model.  Be sure that the game is still good.  In particular, if your focus is "more about data models than graphics" then you have to really be sure that your game's data model fits your framework's capabilities.

Step 5.  Rethink your framework.  Is Django still the right choice?  Perhaps you need to go back to step 3 and learn another framework.  There's nothing wrong with learning a second framework.  Indeed, until you learn another framework, you won't fully *get* Django.

Step 6.  Now you should have enough background to actually implement your game.

Answer (score 6):

If you are considering using Django as your framework, here are just some basic points about it you might find helpful to consider:

Firstly, the Django libraries are written in Python. Therefore, at least a basic knowledge of python is required to develop a site using Django.

Secondly, Django includes its own template system that is useful for integrating with html - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/ .

Thridly, as you've stated that you are more concerned with data models (which I am assuming means you are going to want to store information in some way especially considering it is related to social networking ?) Django also provides for a way to integrate with databases like MySQL and SQLite and the tutorial even walks you through how to set one up if you haven't already - http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/ - and how to integrate with a legacy database if you have - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs .

Lastly, Django enables you to run your site off of their development server which can be really useful for testing and running your site locally before deploying it to the web via Apache or another web server of your choosing - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server .

I would really encourage you to do the online tutorial - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/ - or take a look at Holovaty and Moss's "The Definitive Guide To Django" (available on http://www.djangobook.com/).

Hope this helps!